# What URL's does Google use to comunicate to my app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, admob

What URL's does  Google use to comunicate to my app in terms of Admobs and Firebase database/Realtime database as these are required for connection by my Mobile Network Service Provider for the community app we are working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Realtime Database traffic from your app connects to `<projectname>.firebaseio.com` over HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for your Response Frank, Tell me does that URL apply for AdMobs too? Meaning does AdMobs ads get pushed throug that very same URL as well?

Comment: Nope, as said this is the URL for the Firebase Realtime Database. Maybe someone else can answer for Admob, as I'm not an expert on that. This is one of the many reasons btw why you should limit the scope of your questions on Stack Overflow.